# 19.04 fails to boot due to TPM + secure boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 19.04

I'm trying to run 19.04 on my main desktop computer running on an Asus x99-II motherboard with a TPM. I'm dual booting windows with the idea of enabling BitLocker after Ubuntu is happy.

Since I'm installing Ubuntu on my secondary drive, I manually create a `/boot` partition using ext4 and the main partition '/' as an encrypted drive (I have the same setup on my laptop, but running 18.04). I've also enabled 3rd party proprietary drivers as my desktop has an nVidia video card.

The installation goes well, but after booting, when I try to launch ubuntu from GRUB2 I get a few lines with the error

> Unknown TPM error

and the last line says

> you need to load the kernel first

After that, if I hit a key, I go back to the grub selection screen.

I'm a bit confused why this error shows up. I have a similar setup on my laptop, but both windows and Ubuntu are running on the same physical drive.

I saw a but report on the Debian [bug tracker](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=940911), but there was no reply from the maintainers.

One suggestion on another forum was to disable UEFI and secure boot, but I prefer to keep using UEFI + secure boot. Any ideas what else could I try?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed 19.04 instead of 19.10?
The only version I know of that contains GRUB 2.04 is Ubuntu 19.10 (unless you changed it).

One way to fix is to disable TPM in the BIOS. Although I can't seem to find it on my board, you may have better luck.

Another fix is indeed to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS/UEFI settings, but you don't need to disable UEFI.

---

[This comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1848892/comments/13) provides a possible fix involving editing any grub entry, and a few people in the bug report say it works. However, I cannot guarantee it.